# Printing from Windows Store Apps with out using charms

Tags: c#, printing, windows-store-apps

I am trying to Print receipt from windows store apps without Charms, but I am unable to do that.

Can you please suggest me how to print by single button click from App (without using charms)?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to dump out a file (PDF?) outside the app's sandboxed environment (file picker).  Then have a custom app/process "pick up" the file and send to printer.  Which would be outside the app store.

In my OB1 Kenobi voice - "Use the Charms amanjaneyulu".

Comment: Thanks @Kris Krause, If you have any sample program for pickup file and send to printer by a single click, please post that app here.